# How to check a time array if the single values are in +/- 15 minute range of another time

Tags: php, time, logic, strtotime

What should I do to make a 4 digit integer/string to behave (not look) like time?

Consider this code:

```
$t = 0430;
$timeArray = array('0400', '0415', '0420', '0430', '0440', '0450', '0500', '0600');
```

Now if I have to search `$timeArray` for elements which are +/- 15 min from `$t` I would do this:

```
foreach($timeArray AS $time){
    if($time <= $t + 15 && $time >= $t - 15){
        return $time;
    }
}
```

Shouldn't be a problem. I'll get back:

```
0415, 0420, 0430, 0440
```

But if `$t = 0445` and `$t = 0505` I'd obviously miss out on `0500` and `0450` respectively.

Now how would I make `$t` and/or `$timeArray` elements to behave like time? That 0500 comes after 0459 not 0460?

Edits:

1. Logical hacks welcome. Need not be just in PHP unless ofcourse if you are using a PHP predefined function :)
2. I'm getting "integer time" from a webservice. So if I can convert that into "Time/TimeStamp" that would be great too!
3. My bad. 4 digit string. Like `'0400'`

Comment: all your integers that are smaller than 1000 now is octal representations of integers. I think that you need to learn about bases in PHP.

Comment: Why do you need that 4 digit time? use them as key and store actial time stamp in array.

Comment: @b0s3: Please read my EDIT2

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov My Bad. Those are strings. I have edited the question.

Comment: Before you compare you have to cast to int

Comment: @eNeMetcH So where are we with this question?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov In fact I just learnt it. I just did `$t = 0500; echo $t` I got  320. Thank you very much! **Colateral Knowledge** :)

Comment: @IshaS: No I dont have to do it in PHP. But anyway that was not the problem. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

First convert all strings into timestampes, by looping through all values with `array_map()`.

After this you can simply loop through your values and check if they are in a 15 minute range.

```
<?php

    $t = "0430"; 
    $timeArray = array('0400', '0415', '0420', '0430', '0440', '0450', '0500', '0600');

    $timestampes = array_map("strtotime", $timeArray);
    $t = strtotime($t);

    foreach($timestampes as $time){
        if($time <= $t + (15*60) && $time >= $t - (15*60)){
            echo date("H:i:s", $time) . "<br>";
        }
    }

?>
```

output:

```
04:15:00
04:20:00
04:30:00
04:40:00
```

Comment: But strtotime()convert `$t` and array elements to today's time. So even if date is attached to the array like array('date' => *date*, 'time' => 0400), and since i'm only comparing time, this should still work. That is smart. Thanks!

Comment: @eNeMetcH You're welcome. (Yes, since you only provide the time to `strtotime()` it will just use the current date to create the timestamp)